# XPath: Collecting while aggregating issue

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<person height="170"/>
<person height="155"/>
<person height="192"/>
...
<tree height="100"/>
<tree height="300"/>
<tree height="120"/>
```

I need to return all the persons which have at least 3 trees with height that is in the range of the person's height +- 10.

For example, if a person has height of 155, the person would be returned iff there exists at least 3 trees with heights in the range of 145 to 165.

I tried to implement it and got as far as:

```
//person[count(//tree[@height >>>>>>is in range 10 to person's height<<<<<]) >= 3]
```

I'm stuck implementing the inner part. I tried using "current" and "self" but I don't seem to be using them right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one place where you can use the `for $me in .` idiom:

```
//person[count(for $me in . return //tree[
    @height <= ($me/@height + 10) and @height >= ($me/@height - 10)]) >= 3]
```

Here I'm using a single-iteration `for` expression to capture the current `person` (the `.` of the first-level predicate) so I can refer to it within the second-level predicate (where `.` is the `tree`).

Comment: I would have expected some syntactic sugar to replace this horrible idiom, but it works so I can't complain :)

Comment: @Mugen it always seemed slightly strange to me that `for` is part of XPath but `let` is only XQuery.